# android collapsable searchview with custom header

Tags: android, searchview, collapsable, custom-headers

I need the suggestion for using the best way to show searchview with custom header.

My headerlayout should initially look like this

[image: initial view]

And after clicking the search button on the right of the header, it must replace header title and menu icon part with the search input field like this.

[image: after clicking search icon]

pressing back in this state, should direct to initial state.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to customize the `SearchView`or is a standard one fine for you?
If it is I suggest looking into the `ActionBar` with an `ActionView`

[Android ActionBar documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView)  about adding an ActionView

Comment: Actually I haven't used SearchView yet. So, I guess, whatever suits my purpose with minimum efforts, is fine :)

Comment: I suppose the out of the box `SearchView` will be just fine for you then.

Answer (score 0):

**in Menu Resource directory**
search_country_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
       app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

**In Activity's onCreateOptionmenu Method **

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_country_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).expandActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.select_country));
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
                  return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                etSearch.setText(arg0);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```